# Detect contact and viewing information in text

Tags: parsing, nlp

I'm trying to detect contact information in a huge list of offers I get. The offers contain text without any given structure, some examples could be the following ones:

- if you're interested, send an email to test@test.com
- want to know more? call 000 000 000
- come to the public viewing on 25nd of january
- public viewing is on the coming wednesday
- is this what you're searching for? We're looking forward to hearing from you

As you can see, there are multiple possibilities:

- there is no date for a viewing, but there's a phone number
- there is no date for a viewing, but there's an email
- there is a date for a viewing
- there is no detailed information

The tricky point is, there can also be e.g. other dates in text, therefore I can't just parse out dates.

What is the best way to solve something like that? I've already tried it with regex. I think I could get it work but there is an enormous amount of cases which makes it very hard.

I've also looked into things like NLP with libraries like https://spacy.io/ or [prodi.gy](https://prodi.gy), but I feel like I'm not on the right track.

The original texts are written in German.

In 2020, how do I go after this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a NLP powered Rule-based matcher. With spacy, You explored the right tool, just didn't go deep with it. And it's available in german.
Here are some examples:

Some patterns:

```
#call number
call_pattern = [{'LOWER':'call'},{"ORTH": "(", 'OP':"?"}, {"SHAPE": "ddd"}, {"ORTH": ")", 'OP':"?"}, {"SHAPE": "ddd"},
 {"ORTH": "-", "OP": "?"}, {"SHAPE": "ddd"}]

#e-mail pattern
email_pattern = [{'LIKE_EMAIL': True}]

#pattern for public viewing
public_viewing_pattern = [{'LOWER': 'public'},
           {'LOWER': 'viewing'},
           {'POS': 'AUX', 'OP': '?'},
           {'POS': 'ADP', 'OP': '?'},
           {'label': 'DATE', 'OP':'+'}]
```

Then, you iterate over your patterns and apply them:

```
import spacy
from spacy.matcher import Matcher
nlp = spacy.load('en')
#or:
#import de_core_news_sm
#nlp = de_core_news_sm.load()

matcher = Matcher(nlp.vocab)
matcher.add("call_pattern", None, call_pattern)
matcher.add("email_pattern", None, email_pattern)
matcher.add("public_viewing_pattern", None, public_viewing_pattern)
found = {'numbers':[], 'emails':[], 'public_viewings':[]}
for sent in sentences:
  doc = nlp(sent)
  matches = matcher(doc)
  for match_id, start, end in matches:
    if doc.vocab.strings[match_id] == 'call_pattern':
      found['numbers'].append(doc[start:end])
    if doc.vocab.strings[match_id] == 'email_pattern':
      found['emails'].append(doc[start:end])
    if doc.vocab.strings[match_id] == 'public_viewing_pattern':
      found['public_viewings'].append(doc[start:end])
print(found)
```

result:

> {'numbers': [call 000 000 000], 'emails': [test@test.com], 'public_viewings': [public viewing on, public viewing on 25nd, public viewing on 25nd of, public viewing on 25nd of january, public viewing is, public viewing is on, public viewing is on the, public viewing is on the coming, public viewing is on the coming wednesday]}

Ps.: This repeating is caused by a bug in spacy versions prior to 2.1. Just add some manual validation for repeating matches (get the one with most lenght) and you'll be good.

The hard part will be to generalize enough and correctly get your patterns, but they are very powerful and you can do all sort of tweaks to them. Check [spacy online demo](https://explosion.ai/demos/matcher?text=%0Apublic%20viewing%20is%20on%20the%20coming%20wednesday.%0Ais%20this%20what%20you%27re%20searching%20for%3F%20We%27re%20looking%20forward%20to%20hearing%20from%20you&model=en_core_web_sm&pattern=%5B%7B%22id%22%3A0%2C%22attrs%22%3A%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22LOWER%22%2C%22value%22%3A%22public%22%7D%5D%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A1%2C%22attrs%22%3A%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22LOWER%22%2C%22value%22%3A%22viewing%22%7D%5D%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A3%2C%22attrs%22%3A%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22POS%22%2C%22value%22%3A%22AUX%22%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22OP%22%2C%22value%22%3A%22%3F%22%7D%5D%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A4%2C%22attrs%22%3A%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22POS%22%2C%22value%22%3A%22ADP%22%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22OP%22%2C%22value%22%3A%22%3F%22%7D%5D%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A5%2C%22attrs%22%3A%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22ENT_TYPE%22%2C%22value%22%3A%22DATE%22%7D%5D%7D%5D) for testing. Also, refer to the [manual](https://spacy.io/usage/rule-based-matching/) for more complex stuff.